# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de implementar TOASTR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 4, C#, necesito implementar toastr  siguiendo un manual lo implemente del lado del servidor y se hace una sola vez con una clase base. [Extend MVC controller to support Toastr messages](http://labs.bjfocus.co.uk/2014/06/extend-mvc-controller-to-support-toastr-messages/)

Pero también recomiendan implementarlo del lado del cliente, el cual se implementa con javascript y siempre que lo use.

¿cual es la forma correcta de implementar esta libreria de notificaciones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias darle una mirada al articulo previo

[Create an MVC wrapper for Toastr](http://labs.bjfocus.co.uk/2014/06/create-an-mvc-wrapper-for-toastr/)

Esta claro que lo que realiza desde el servidor es un componente que genera el javascript dinamico que injecta en el render de la view, no esta haciendo nada del otro mundo, para lanzar el toast despues del post al servidor genera javascript desde codig .net que injecta en la view y llega al browser

- Si lo implementas generando el mensaje del lado del servidor vas a
  necesitar un submit al action del controller para lanzar el mensaje
- Si lo implementas como codigo cliente entonces deberias usar ajax
  para invocar el action que retorne la info que indique si debes
  desplegar el toast o no

**>>¿cual es la forma correcta de implementar esta libreria de notificaciones?**

No hay una forma correcta, depende de como quieras implementarlo, si con submit de la pagina o sin este

las veces que yo lo use no implemente nada del lado del servidor, solo con un .js y .css y despues codigo cliente con javascript, jquery o angular realizando llamadas al servidor por medio de ajax

Comment: Ok, del lado del Cliente es lo mejor, por otro lado como usaría el Toastr en un JsonResult?

Comment: si invocas el action que devuelve el json simplemente tienes que usar la api de la libreria javascript que implementa el js de toast, en el success de la llamada al action es donde realizas esto